# Help to identify a tree South Florida

Tags: trees

Can anyone help me identify this tree?  I'm located in South Florida[image]

Comment: Ficus Lyrata, see the excellent answer to the same question in the link

Comment: Get rid of the plastic.  Unless you are a nursery, planting in pots, dealing with bare ground, selling product...get rid of it.